# Get current currency being used's symbol in Woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am modifying a plugin to add different charges for cash on delivery for different currencies. The site uses multicurrency option. How can I get the current currency being used?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For example :

```
if(get_woocommerce_currency() =='USD'){
    echo 'Currency is USA dollar';
}
else{
    echo 'Currency is not USA dollar';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

we can get current currency [get_woocommerce_currency()](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/function-get_woocommerce_currency.html) For current currency symbol we can use [get_woocommerce_currency_symbol()](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/function-get_woocommerce_currency_symbol.html).

Comment: How do I know the currencies I am using? What exact string should I used to compare? like "US" for dollar.

Comment: get_woocommerce_currency() function return exact string that you are looking . For example, if you have set the US dollar, It would return USD string. You can test it by just printing this function in the header or anywhere you like. You would get the exact result and then you can add that string to your switch statement or conditional statement.