# Make a number in a text act as a price in Woocommerce

Tags: html, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, custom-wordpress-pages, currency-formatting

I have an issue with my multicurrency website.
I fully configured WooCommerce Payments Multi-Currency, and everything functions as intended on my category and product pages.

---

The problem is that plain numbers and text that were utilized as price indicators on the website outside the woocommerce "scope" inadvertently do not convert on currency switch. 
Say, "This thing costs **55 euros**."
such as in some of my homepage's titles or in arbitrary text in blog posts.

---

I tried to add this HTML:

`<span class="price"><span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><bdi>55&nbsp;<span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">€</span></bdi></span></span>`

It shows the price in € but unfortunately, it does not get converted on currency switch.

Would you know how to "inform" WooCommerce that these numbers are in fact prices that also need to be converted when changing currencie.

*Do not hesitate to tell me if it is not clear, English is not my first language!*

**Thanks!**

Comment: Welcome! Try using `echo get_woocommerce_currency()` in place of the Euro symbol.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get current currency being used's symbol in Woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47771336/get-current-currency-being-useds-symbol-in-woocommerce)

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply!  It does not seem to work or I could do it wrong. Let's say I have a title written in HTML like this:  <h1>shoes&nbsp;28.5&nbsp;€</h1>  How can i make it so the currency switch affect him to ?

Comment: If anyone is wondering i found the solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54512834/how-to-display-woocommerce-price-on-products-body-text-using-shortcode